# Can C++ programmers choose where memory goes in the heap?

Tags: c++

I was under the impression that in C++ the programmer as no say in where the memory in the heap is placed. Now that I am getting further in my textbook I realize that I could have been wrong because memory management all about preventing fragmentation and I feel like you can't really prevent fragmentation efficiently without someone reorganizing the heap.

How wrong am I on this one? Any links would be a appreciated!

EDIT: A comment clarified this for me and I wanted to add it to the post incase anyone else looks at what I said and thinks I know what I am talking about. " memory management all about preventing fragmentation" is not true at all. It is a very small part of memory management and sometimes irrelevant.

Comment: "Memory management is all about preventing fragmentation". No its not, thats a very minor and usually totally irrelevant thing outside of some special scenarios.

Comment: The OS memory manager determines where in physical memory a process is mapped. Programmatically, you have no control over that. From a C++ `new`/`delete` or allocation via a STL container, where and what address is used is out of your control (the answer differs in a *Freestanding Implementation* -- without an OS where you define the memory regions outside C++) Whether or not fragmentation occurs and how it is handled is largely outside of your direct control. There are allocation schemes for page-size blocks of memory that can minimize fragmentation -- but that's not usually a concern.

Comment: This sounds like an *XY Problem*. See: [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) What problem are you facing and why do you think reorganizing the heap would provide a solution?

Comment: Most OSes provide APIs to let you create your own memory heaps, which you can use however you want. And standard C++ containers let you create your own `Allocator` classes. And you can use `placement-new` to create objects inside of pre-existing memory. So saying that you have no control over memory management is not true.

Comment: Memory management is about ensuring all allocated resources are deallocated exactly once and correctly.  Fragmentation results from the common scenario where the programmer repeatedly allocates, deallocates, and reallocates memory of arbitrary sizes and in arbitrary order.  Some memory management techniques prevent fragmentation, by significantly constraining how memory allocation and deallocation are performed (e.g. only permit fixed size allocations, order of deallocations must be the exact reverse order of allocations).  Programmers tend to whine when required to adhere to such constraints.

Answer (score 1):

> Can C++ programmers choose where memory goes in the heap?

It depends.

If you're using a self-hosted C++ implementation on hardware without an operating system and without virtual memory, then you can basically treat the entire physical memory as "allocated" for your program, and build your own heap.

If your program runs within a modern operating system, then "where" memory is in the virtual space is separate from where memory is "physically". The OS handles the mapping in a way that is entirely transparent to your program. Within standard C++, you don't even get say which parts of the virtual memory are allocated.